# How do i import my ethereum wallet just using private key?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, web3j, android, smart-contract-wallets

Help me out how do i resolve the issue of ethereum smartcontract for getting my wallet when i enter my private key in the text area

```
Use WalletUtils functionality
The WalletUtils class can be used to load your credentials from various 
formats:

WalletUtils.loadCredentials(String password,String source)
WalletUtils.loadBip39Credentials(String password,String mnemonic)
WalletUtils.loadBip39Credentials(String password,String mnemonic)
WalletUtils.loadJsonCredentials(String password,String content)
```

http://docs.web3j.io/latest/transactions/credentials/#use-walletutils-functionality

These are the methods provided by the web3j library can anyone help me out to import my wallet from
ethereum using private key??

Answer (score 0):

The methods listed on the question are related to `wallet` usage.

However, on the same [link](http://docs.web3j.io/latest/transactions/credentials/#use-walletutils-functionality), the `org.web3j.crypto.Credentials` class is also listed as a wrapper to handle raw keys. This latter has a `create` method with different overloads you can use.

So, if you have a raw private key that you want to use to load credentials, you can use the following:

```
org.web3j.crypto.Credentials.create(String privateKey)
```